# Swing to JavaFX2.0

Tags: javafx

I’m moving from Swing to JavaFX2.0. I have an internal service with various JFrame windows to display/alter internal parameters. I have a menu with buttons. Each button kicks off one of the JFrame windows as such:

```
new ASvr().setVisible(true);
```

Works fine. Now going to JavaFX2.0: Each “window” is an independent FXML application. The independent FXML applications run as standalone applications when the service is remote using RPC to communicate with the service. This is the internal version where the “windows” are part of the same JVM.

The Menu starts with application.launch(). There can only be one launch() in the JVM so I can’t use launch() for the independent FXML applications. After much trial and error (mostly error) what I’ve come up with is:

```
new ASvr().start(new Stage());
```

Works fine, I think. Since I’m new to JavaFX I could be missing something which will ruin this solution. Calling start() myself, not from a launch(), may have nasty side effects. I can’t use a new ProcessBuilder and put each application inside a new JVM since I need direct access to references within the internal service.

My questions: Is there a preferred way to have several independent (need to run as standalone without alteration) FXML application scenes running within a JVM? Do you see any potential problems with what I did?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not recommend calling `start(...)` yourself. The `launch(...)` method does a lot of complex housekeeping, such as starting the FX toolkit and the FX Application Thread, instantiating the application class, and then invoking `start(...)` on the FX Application thread.

You should basically think of `start(...)` as the equivalent of the `main(...)` method for a JavaFX application, and the `Application` subclass as the "main-class", not the `JFrame` subclass. (Indeed, in Java 8, if your class is a subclass of `Application` it can be launched directly by the JVM without even having a `main(...)` method.)

Once you have created your single `start(...)` method (again, just think of it as the replacement for your single `main(...)` entry point from a "regular" Java application), then you can show the contents of an FXML file with the idiom

```
Stage stage = new Stage();
stage.setScene(new Scene(FXMLLoader.load(fxmlResource));
stage.show();
```

(Of course, there are variations on this, especially if you need access to the controller, but you get the idea.)

You could if you wanted create subclasses of `Stage`, in the old swing style of creating `JFrame` subclasses, and let the constructor of the `Stage` subclass load its FXML and set its own scene. Then you could use essentially the same idiom as you used in Swing:

```
new MyStageSubclass().show();
```

Notice again how the analogue of a `JFrame` subclass is a `Stage` subclass, not an `Application` subclass.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have a launch() already when the Menu starts so the housekeeping is done. I can’t alter the subsequent FXML applications since they need to run independently in a RPC environment. What you suggest means altering the other applications since each of them has a start() within that loads the FXML file. Your approach is interesting and worth a try. It’s going to take a while to play around with it.

Comment: You can still keep those independent applications (so you can run them on their own), but from the "menu application" just load up the FXML file; don't call the `start(...)` method. In other words, the FXML file is the reusable component; the `Application` subclass is not.

Comment: OK I'll give it a whirl.