# How to start new JavaFX (Application) thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I want to create a program in Java with a main window, that can open more subprograms in other windows.

I created a simple JavaFX program for the main window, and it works as expected, like so:

```
public class MainThread extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // code goes here...

    }
}
```

... and I created other Java classes the same way.

I tried to run them simply with `new SubProgramThread();`- as I would create a new instance of any object- but that hasn't worked for me- it doesn't run the `start()` method in the subprogram classes.

Is that the right way to create an `Application` instance?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you actually mean to run different programs in different windows, or do you just want to have different windows?

Comment: @fge They're different threads of the same process in different windows- it's still under the same Java program.

Comment: Well, you cannot really do that since for a same JVM, there can be only one JavaFX application thread (as far as I know, at least); but that does not prevent you from having several windows (each must have its own `Stage`, though; but this is doable)

Comment: @fge I tried to create new `Stage`s and it worked! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this all the time. I have a menu of items. When a user clicks the item button I create the new window by calling start() on the FX class:

```
new TyAltSvr().start(new Stage());
```

[Some people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27554089/swing-to-javafx2-0) don't like calling start() but it hasn't caused me any problems.

Comment: Thanks but I think I like fge's comment better: to create a new `Stage` rather than a whole new JavaFX `Application`. Would there be an advantage of creating a new  `Application` instance?

Comment: @jlam55555 I am creating a new Stage: start(new Stage))); The new Stage is passed to start().